# C++ array initialization

Tags: c++, syntax

is this form  of intializing an array to all 0s

`char myarray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0}`   supported by all compilers? ,

if so, is there similar syntax to other types? for example

```
bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {false}
```

Comment: I bet good money `false` is the same as `0` (otherwise `if(false)` wouldn't evaluate to false), so what you have will probably work on 99% of compilers. Can't be sure about the other 1% until we cite the standard.

Comment: I know that in C, `int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3 };` will set `a[3]..a[9]` to `0`, ("initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration").  Does this hold true for C++?

Comment: Yes, it does. If it didn't hold true for C++ then C++ wouldn't be even remotely backwards compatible with C.

Comment: `false` is not the same as `0`, but in `{0}` the 0 is converted to `false`, and in (for C++) `{}` you don't even have to care about conversions: It's initialized to `false` or `0` or null-pointer or any other type-sensitive default.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Yes, this form of initialization is supported by all C++ compilers. It is a part of C++ language. In fact, it is an idiom that came to C++ from C language. In C language `= { 0 }` is an idiomatic *universal zero-initializer*. This is also *almost* the case in C++.

Since this initalizer is universal, for `bool` array you don't really need a different "syntax". `0` works as an initializer for `bool` type as well, so

```
bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 0 };
```

is guaranteed to initialize the entire array with `false`. As well as

```
char* myPtrArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 0 };
```

in guaranteed to initialize the whole array with null-pointers of type `char *`.

If you believe it improves readability, you can certainly use

```
bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { false };
char* myPtrArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { nullptr };
```

but the point is that `= { 0 }` variant gives you *exactly* the same result.

However, in C++ `= { 0 }` might not work for all types, like enum types, for example, which cannot be initialized with integral `0`. But C++ supports the shorter form

```
T myArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {};
```

i.e. just an empty pair of `{}`. This will default-initialize an array of any type (assuming the elements allow default initialization), which means that for basic (scalar) types the entire array will be properly zero-initialized.

Comment: and in c++0x you will be able to initialise anything like this

Comment: On my compiler (qt creator 2.4.1 - qt version 4.8.0) if I write `bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { false };` the array is all initialized to false, but if i write `bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { true };` only the first element is set to true, while everything else is false. Any explaination?

Comment: @rookie coder: Explanation for what exactly? What do you expect should happen? In C++, if you *partially* initialize a `bool` array, the rest is zero-initialized for you. That's just the way it is.

Comment: @AndreyT Fine, but I find this behaviour at least counter-intuitive. If I don't initialize, like `bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE];`, the array rightfully contains random values, therefore I wouldn't have expected that an initialization could return an array with different values in it. That's all.

Comment: @rookie coder: Initialization in C and C++ follows "all-or-nothing" principle. If you attempt to initialize just a part of something, you always trigger an "avalanche" that causes full initialization.

Comment: @AndreyT: sure, but I'd never have thought that the avalanche would have been different from the first element ;-) Anyway, thanks for the infos!

Comment: @AnT "However, in C++ = { 0 } might not work for all types, like enum types". What about `C`?

Comment: @AnT "In C language = { 0 } is an idiomatic universal zero-initializer", but `{true}` is not. So `bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { true };` only guarantee the first element to be `true` other than all the elements to be `true`. Can I understand that in this way?

Comment: @rookiecoder "In C language = { 0 } is an idiomatic universal zero-initializer", but {true} is not. So bool myBoolArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = { true }; only guarantee the first element to be true other than all the elements to be true. Can I understand that in this way? Seven years later,how do you think about it now?

Comment: @John first element is initialized with the value, the rest with the default initialization, which is zero (therefore false). You can use `std::fill_n(myBoolArray, ARRAY_SIZE, true);` to set everything to true.

Comment: is ARRAY_SIZE an int?  I'm getting red squiggly under vecSize for this:`            int instructionArr[vecSize] = {0};`

Answer (score 21):

Note that the '=' is optional in C++11 universal initialization syntax, and it is generally considered better style to write :

```
char myarray[ARRAY_SIZE] {0}
```

Comment: How to understand `char myarray[ARRAY_SIZE] {0}`? Init the each element of `myarray` for `ARRAY_SIZE` times?

Comment: @John init first element to `0`, default init others (which in this case is zero init).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe it should work and it can also be applied to other data types.

For class arrays though, if there are fewer items in the initializer list than elements in the array, the default constructor is used for the remaining elements. If no default constructor is defined for the class, the initializer list must be complete — that is, there must be one initializer for each element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, keep a note of how the `array` and `vector` are default initialized if don't initialize them explicitly.

```
int main()
{
    bool arr1[3];                   // true  true  true  [here true is SOME garbage value] 
    std::vector<bool> vec1(3);      // false false false

    bool arr2[3] = { true };        // true false false [here true/false are REAL true/false values] 
    vector<bool> vec2(3, true);     // true true  true

    bool arr3[3] = { false };         // false false false
    std::vector<bool> vec3(3, false); // false false false


    int arr4[3];                      // GV GV GV - garbage value
    std::vector<int> vec4(3);         // 0 0 0

    int arr5[3] = { 1 };              // 1 0 0
    std::vector<int> vec5(3, 1);      // 1 1 1

    int arr6[3] = { 0 };              // 0 0 0
    std::vector<int> vec6(3, 0);      // 0 0 0
}
```

Comment: Don't write `true` or `false` if you don't mean `true` or `false`. It is realy confusing and misleading. Write `x`or `y`or `<unspecified>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the array in C++ in these type of ways.
If you know the array size then you should declare the array for:
integer: `int myArray[array_size];`
Double: `double myArray[array_size];`
Char and string : `char myStringArray[array_size];`
The difference between char and string is as follows

```
char myCharArray[6]={'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
char myStringArray[6]="abcdef";
```

If you don't know the size of array then you should leave the array blank like following.

integer: `int myArray[array_size];`

Double: `double myArray[array_size];`