# how do i use fill_n() on the following array?

Tags: c++, arrays, fill

I have this array

```
 unsigned char        bit_table_[10][100];
```

What is the right way to fill it with 0.
I tried

```
std::fill_n(bit_table_,sizeof(bit_table_),0x00);
```

but vc 2010 flags it as error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c), [C++ array initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920430/)

Comment: i have no problem in initializing it when it is just a one dimension. My problem is when I have two dimension or more,

Comment: Is the use of `fill_n` a requirement or simply how you're attempting to solve another problem? Be careful your question doesn't suffer from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: may be `std::fill_n(&bit_table_[0][0],sizeof(bit_table_),0x00);` will work.

Comment: `bit_table_` isn't a two-dimensional array, it's an array of pointers. If the elements of `bit_table_` are supposed to point to arrays, you'll need to allocate those before initializing them. In either case, this is still a duplicate, as there are also plenty of questions about zero-initializing multidimensional arrays.

Comment: i have to use the fill_n because i have read somewhere that memset is not always safe

Comment: @John: `memset` is generally safe for data types for which the zero bit pattern is well defined. That's the case for every builtin type (of which I am aware...), as well as every POD type (again, of which I am aware). More to the point, if you're seeing a compiler error, include the entire error (minus long file names, of course) in the question. It makes it easier for people to see why the compiler may be complaining; often the fault is not in the code that you post.

Comment: @luxun: Sorry I never have done so. I am just new to this kind of Q&As. I have found many helpful answers from you guys and wanna thank you all for that. And I will remember to accept answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On initialization:

```
unsigned char bit_table_[10][100] = {};
```

If it's a class member, you can initialize it in the constructor, like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
    :bit_table_()
{}
```

Otherwise:

```
std::fill_n(*bit_table_,sizeof(bit_table_),0);
```

Comment: i have tried the first one but it is not possible because bit_table_ is data member of a class. The second one, I will just try it now.

Comment: @John: For a member, there is another way, see updated answer.

Comment: sizeof(bit_table_) works in this case because you are using byte-sized pieces.  If you want to use fill_n on something bigger: `double doubles[10][100];` then you use the dimensions of the array for the second parameter: `std::fill_n(*doubles, 10*100, 123.45);`

Answer (score 2):

The type of `bit_table_` is `unsigned char [10][100]`, which will decay (that is, the compiler allows it to be implicitly converted to) into `unsigned char (*)[100]`, that is, a pointer to an array of 100 `unsigned chars`.

`std::fill_n(bit_table_, ...)` is then instantiated as: 
`std::fill_n(unsigned char (*)[100], ...)` which means it expects a value of type `unsigned char [100]` to initialize `bit_table_` with. `0` is not convertible to that type, so the compilation fails.

Another way to think about it is that the STL functions that deal with iterators only deal with a single dimension. If you are passing in a multidimensional structure those STL functions will only deal with a single dimension.

Ultimately, you can't do this; there is no way to assign to an array type. I.e., since you can't do this:

```
char table[100];
char another_table[100]= { };
table= another_table;
```

you can't use `std::fill_n` on multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try  `unsigned char bit_table_[10][100]= { 0 }` to fill it with zeros.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char        bit_table_[10][100]= { 0 };
    return 0;

}
```