# What is this error "test: malloc.c:2388: sysmalloc: Assertion ... failed"

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc

EDIT: I have gotten it solved and put my new code below.  Thank's every for your help!

I have an array of null pointers and I'm trying to set an array element at a certain index to point to an object of a class I've created but I end up with this error:

```
test: malloc.c:2388: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

Code:

```
Trie::Trie() {
    word = false;
    for(int i=0; i<26; i=i+1) {
        children[i]={NULL};
    }
}

Trie::~Trie() {
    for(int i=0; i<26; i=i+1) {
        delete children[i];
    }
}

Trie::Trie( const Trie &obj) {}

void Trie::addWord(string word) {
    //Subtract 97 to turn character into index
    //Once word is empty then we need to set the node to true
    cout << word << " was seen\n";
    char first = word.at(0);
    int index = first - 97;
    string stringToSend = word.substr(1);
    Trie * currentNode = children[index];
    if(stringToSend.empty()) {
        this -> word = true;
        return;
    }
    if(currentNode == NULL) {
        currentNode = new Trie();
    }
    currentNode ->addWord(stringToSend);
}
```

Here is Trie.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Trie {
    //Data Variables
    //char value;
    bool word;
    Trie* children[26];
    public:
        Trie(); //Constructor
        Trie( const Trie &obj);
        ~Trie(); //Deconstructor
        void addWord(string);
        bool isWord(string);
        vector<string> allWordsWithPrefix(string);
};
```

Comment: The debugger will track down the exact line that causes the problem if you step through the code. What line generates that error?

Comment: You're missing the definition of the `class Trie` itself. So there's no useful information as to what `children` is.

Comment: In case you mean to initialize 26 elements of the array with `children[26]={NULL};`, that's utterly wrong. This only changes the 26th element. To change the whole array, use a loop, or better yet a standard container like  vector.

Comment: I'm fairly sure 'new' is telling you that you've corrupted the heap memory state. There's a lot of places in that code where you're probably following a random pointer and writing stuff to it.

Comment: iksemyonov, yes that is what I am trying to do.  Are you sure I can't do that? I am following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920430/c-array-initialization

Comment: TBBle,  do you mean my header file? I can post that too if needed.

Comment: Another problem is that `index` may be out of bounds. Further, `children[index]->word` should not occur before `children[index] = new Trie();`

Comment: `char myarray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};` is completely different to `myarray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};`  . You can't just drop off a word and assume it does the same thing...

Comment: Crashes in `new` or `delete` are almost always caused by memory corruption. Try running your program in `valgrind` for more accurate information.

Comment: The question should show the declaration of `children`.  (Even better, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See above, as @M.M. has noticed, the question in the link shows how an array is declared and initialized at the same time. You are, on the contrary, changing an already declared array. The array is declared where the `class Trie` is.

Comment: children is a member variable and I was trying to initialize it in the constructor

Comment: Yes, but you do not *declare* it in the constructor, while the linked syntax works only for declarations.

Comment: Ah right.  So in the constructor I should just loop through it and set each one to null?

Comment: @iksemyonov, @Tanner It's also possible to fill a C-style array with something like `std::fill(std::begin(children), std::end(children), NULL);`, where `fill()` is in `<algorithm>`, and `begin()` & `end()` are in a lot of standard headers (such as `<iterator>`, `<vector>`, or `<array>`), provided your compiler supports C++11.  Example here: http://ideone.com/jOvgjO

Comment: See my complete answer below. It's better to refrain from lengthy discussion in comments, if I understand the rules correctly. Justin Time, I've attached your valuable addition to my answer, thank you!

Comment: @iksemyonov You're welcome.  I came across `fill()` when I was learning about `std::array` a while back, and figured that since other range-based functions work with C-style arrays, it would too.

Answer (score 1):

`Trie::children` is not dynamically allocated, so you cannot `delete[]` it.  The pointers in `Trie::children` may point to dynamically allocated objects, but the pointers themselves were not allocated with `new[]`.  In your destructor, you need to loop over `children` and `delete` each element individually.

Comment: Thanks, that cleaned up a warning but it did not fix the error I was getting.

Answer (score 1):

If anything, in the absence of complete code, I'd point at this line:

```
if(stringToSend.empty()) {
    children[index] -> word = true;
}
```

Where `children[index]` appears to be (again, no code but deduction) a pointer to `Trie`. So this is dereferencing an uninitialized pointer and begs for a crash.

This, correct per se, check should precede dereferencing (reverse order):

```
if(children[index] == NULL) {
    children[index] = new Trie();
}
if(stringToSend.empty()) {
    children[index] -> word = true;
}
```

Edit:

Regarding `children[26]={NULL};` and [convenient array initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920430/c-array-initialization).

Compare:

```
children[26]={nullptr};
```

and

```
Trie* children[26] = {nullptr};
```

The difference is only "one word", but it makes a difference. The first line is changing an already declared array, while the second one is declaring and at the same time initializing an existing array, where the new syntax is being used.

To fill the array with zeroes, use a simple loop like

```
for(auto& p: children) p = nullptr;
```

or, as Justin Time has suggested in the comments above,

```
std::fill(std::begin(children), std::end(children), nullptr);
```

where `fill()` is in `<algorithm>`, and `begin()` & `end()` are declared  in a lot of standard headers (such as `<iterator>`, `<vector>`, or `<array>`). This requires your compiler to support C++11.

Comment: children[26]={NULL}; ended up being the issue.  I now just loop through and initalize each element to NULL.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: using this approach, another issue is that the destructor needs to loop over the array deleting each pointer, instead of its current code

Comment: True, good catch. I tried to concentrate on OP's misunderstanding and the critical error. Your answer is gorgeous!

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of `children` should look like:

```
array<unique_ptr<Trie>, 26> children;
```

You may need `#include <array>` and `#include <memory>` for this. Also, `word` needs an initializer, e.g.:

```
bool word{};
```

Currently your code leaves `word` uninitialized. In fact I would recommend renaming this variable. The name should indicate what it means (AFAICT it is indicating a leaf node); and also it would avoid clashing with the parameter name `word` in your `addWord` function.

Then you do not need to write anything in particular about `children` in the constructor or destructor. In fact you do not need to declare the destructor at all, which is a good thing .

The `addWord` function could look like this:

```
void Trie::addWord(string word)
{
    auto index = word.at(0) - 'a';

    if ( index < 0 || index >= children.size() )
          return;    // or throw exception

    string stringToSend = word.substr(1);

    auto &child = children[index];

    if ( !child )
        child = make_unique<Trie>();

    if ( stringToSend.empty() )
        child->word = true;

    else 
        child->addWord(stringToSend);
}
```

I assume `child->addWord(stringToSend)` was meant to be in an `else`, otherwise you will throw an exception upon hitting `word.at(0)` with the empty string.

Comment: I assume that in 2016, `unique_ptr<>` and its helpers have become the standard way of working with memory? At school we had none of that, and I have troubles understanding where these are (not) required.

Comment: Thanks for the reply M.M.  This was very helpful

Comment: @iksemyonov `unique_ptr` indicates that this pointer 'owns' the memory it points to.  One benefit of this is that someone reading the code does not have to start thinking about who the owner is and who's responsible for deletion. A second benefit is that you can follow the Rule of Zero in your code. A third benefit is that if your code does commit a Rule of Three violation, then you get a compile error, instead of double-deletes at runtime as you would with raw pointers.

Comment: Great, reading up on that! C++ appears to have evolved since my school days.